# Are query criteria in the Select statement equivalent to the same criteria in the Where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**EDIT**: I realize now the silly mistake I have made. It's early in the morning here, and I haven't had my coffee lol, don't flame me too hard for this stupid question. I would delete it if I could. *Major face palm moment guys*. I will slink away in silence now.

If I place the search constraints of my query in the Select clause, like shown:

```
select 
ra.TRADE_FIRM, ra.TRADE_OFFICE, ra.TRADE_REP, c.FIRST_NAME, c.MIDDLE_NAME, c.LAST_NAME, 
c.SUFFIX, ca.ADDRESS_LINE_1, ca.ADDRESS_LINE_2, ca.CITY, ca.STATE_PROVINCE, c.EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
c.BUSINESS_PHONE, c.BUSINESS_PHONE_2, rp.CHANNEL, rp.TERR1, rp.TERR1_LOCKED, 
rp.TERR2, rp.CRD_NUMBER, PRIMARY_YN = 'y', RECORD_TYPE = 'I' --here are my constraints

from dbo.CONTACT c
inner join dbo.CONTACT_ADDRESS ca on ca.CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID = c.ADDRESS_1_ID
inner join dbo.REP_PROFILE rp on rp.CONTACT_ID = c.CONTACT_ID
inner join dbo.REP_ALIAS ra on ra.CONTACT_ID = c.CONTACT_ID
```

Is it logically equivalent to placing them in the Were clause, like this:

```
select 
ra.TRADE_FIRM, ra.TRADE_OFFICE, ra.TRADE_REP, c.FIRST_NAME, c.MIDDLE_NAME, c.LAST_NAME, 
c.SUFFIX, ca.ADDRESS_LINE_1, ca.ADDRESS_LINE_2, ca.CITY, ca.STATE_PROVINCE, c.EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
c.BUSINESS_PHONE, c.BUSINESS_PHONE_2, rp.CHANNEL, rp.TERR1, rp.TERR1_LOCKED, 
rp.TERR2, rp.CRD_NUMBER

from dbo.CONTACT c
inner join dbo.CONTACT_ADDRESS ca on ca.CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID = c.ADDRESS_1_ID
inner join dbo.REP_PROFILE rp on rp.CONTACT_ID = c.CONTACT_ID
inner join dbo.REP_ALIAS ra on ra.CONTACT_ID = c.CONTACT_ID

where
PRIMARY_YN = 'y' and
RECORD_TYPE = 'I'
```

I ask because at first glance, I would think the two options are equivalent, and will yield the same results. But the total number of records returned for each query is different, which is why I am asking SO.

Comment: Besides the fact the the syntax isn't allowed, they do very different things.  The `where` clause *filters* rows.  The `select` clause returns columns.  So, they do not do the same thing.

Comment: In the first query `PRIMARY_YN = 'y'` and `RECORD_TYPE = 'I'` are not constraints.  Those are literals, and are equivalent to `SELECT 'y' AS PRIMARY_YN, 'I' AS RECORD_TYPE`.

Comment: @DMason I'd never tried that kind of query, but I assumed that's what they'd do.  Glad someone could confirm that for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that what you did in the `SELECT` statement is only a dynamic column with the value you provided, so for each record the `PRIMARY_YN`  will always be 'y' even if the value in the table is different.

The only place you can filter the query is the `WHERE` clause or `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: Lol crap. I completely see what I did now. This was a face-palm moment. Wow.